# "this" keyword with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I understand that "this" keyword refers to the currrent/immediate object. While watching a React.js tutorial, I saw the instructor using the keyword with multiple objects. The code looks like this:

```
class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };

  styles = {
    fontSize: 10
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 style={this.styles}>Hello</h1>
        <span>{this.formatCount()}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }

  formatCount() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }
}
```

Inside formatCount(), why we are referring to `this.state` instead of `state.count` ? Also, why not `formatCount()`  instead of `this.formatCount()`? The instructor keeps saying `this` refers to the current object, but he is writing `this.objectname.properties` everytime. Why is that? Can't I distinguish the objects only with the objectname?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your instructor is using [public field declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Field_declarations) within the class.

If it helps your understanding, the equivalent code without this feature would be:

```
class Counter extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };

    this.styles = {
      fontSize: 10
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 style={this.styles}>Hello</h1>
        <span>{this.formatCount()}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }

  formatCount() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }
}
```

In other words, `state = {...}` and `styles = {...}` are just a shorthand for declaring `this.state` and `this.styles` in the constructor method.

Edit: In case you'd like to better understand the `this` keyword, here's [another question you can reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

Comment: To complete the answer, please mention that const { count } = this.state is just a shorthand for const count = this.state.count, OP was unlucky to see it for the first time while still learning about the "this" keyword and probably thinks it's related to her question :)

Comment: I'm not sure that's where their confusion was, but that's [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Comment: You're probably right now that I think about it, but who knows, might've added to the confusion

Comment: Adding to that, does the variable within `{ } ` is a shorthand for represnting the values that are dynamically generated by the javascript?

Comment: If you mean `const { count } = this.state;` that's the same as `const count = this.state.count;` just a different syntax (see the link in comment above).